# After installing Ubuntu I can't boot Windows 8 anymore

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, boot-repair

I just bought a new laptop (a lenovo ideapad Z500) and it came installed with Windows 8. I wanted to have Ubuntu on it too, therefore I resized the Win8 partition from the control panel and installed Ubuntu on the free space I created. 
Ubuntu works perfectly, Windows does not load anymore...  
I tried the recommended repair with Boot-Repair but it did not fix, now I get a "Windows boot loader failed to start" on startup and then I get the GRUB screen. 
The partition summery created by Boot-Repair is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1444837/. 
How can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: some more info after trying this for yet another. It looks like I'm not the only one having troubles with this, it seems that the whole Lenovo Z series is affected by this. I tried so far:

- I've followed this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
  I could not get the Live CD to boot. Tried the same with Live USB, no luck. The CD is not detected as a bootable device, the PC keeps rebooting with the live USB inserted.
- I've also tried this guide: http: //www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/

No luck either, I get the Win 8 boot loader but I get an error message whenever I try to launch ubuntu  UNLESS I accessed the BIOS and altered the boot order, in order to have Ubuntu on top of the list. This way I can access Ubuntu but not Win 8, unless alter the boot order again...

- Standard install from CD. After the installation completed I could not get Win 8 to boot anymore. Used boot-repair and I still had could not get Win 8 to boot.

Still looking for an acceptable solution, thanks for your help.

Comment: did you disabled UEFI for installing ubuntu? then you might need to reinstall windows 8

Comment: No I didn't... But I still can't boot Win 8 after installing ubuntu.

Comment: Please disable SecureBoot (and FastBoot) in your BIOS, then run Boot-Repair again, and indicate the new URL.

Comment: are you running 32 or 64 bit ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried the whole process with Secure Boot and Fast Boot disabled, ran Boot-Repair after installing Ubuntu and now I can get to Windows 8 by choosing "Windows UEFI Recovery" on GRUB. I think, but I'm not sure; that Boot Repair was updated in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

try using an windows 8 cd and boot it up and check if it has an repair feature,it should have it,and then repair it.Something similar happened to me with windows 7 and repaired it with my windows 7 installation disc.

Comment: I do not have a Windows 8 cd, since it is pre-installed in a rescue partition. I can only restore the PC to it's initial state (but then I lose the Ubuntu partition).

Comment: Actually, I think it does not delete the data from the ubuntu partition, but I do not get to choose which OS to boot anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try the menu entry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader)". This is the boot loader which is stored in the EFI system partition and might work better than booting Windows 8 directly from its partition...

Comment: I tried and it did not help.

Comment: See my blog post about this topic: http://falstaff.agner.ch/2012/12/18/ubuntu-12-10-and-windows-8-with-secure-boot-mode/

Are you in Secure Boot Mode?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to redo the Windows boot loader. More help here: https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Note: So far Windows 8 and Linux is problematic with the Secure Boot features. Expect bugs.

Answer (score -1):

I guess we both have (just had) the same issue. I am afraid we installed Ubuntu's bootloader over Windows 8's bootloader. Since "Windows hates Linux" and due to "secure boot tech" we got ourselves in a damn trouble. **Here's a way to make each bootloader work correctly and separately from the other.**

The Windows loader is installed on the first partition (disk 0 partition 1) of your hard disk. What has gone wrong is that we installed Ubuntu's boot loader also over the same partition. The solution is:

1. You should format that partition (surf the net first) this way both loaders are deleted.
2. Install Windows 8 *normally*.
3. Install Ubuntu and be sure not to install the bootloader on partition 0.

P.S. Deleting partition 0 might get u another problem please do more researches about it.

Comment: Please note device 0 partition 0 is 'disk 0 partition 1' sorry for the mistake