# Dual boot Windows with Ubuntu 12.10 UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have recently bought a Lenovo thinkpad edge with Windows 8 preinstalled on it, and I installed Ubuntu 12.10

I mostly followed the instructions under 'General instructions' here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
except I chose 'Something else' as an option when installing and then didn't create a new efi partition for Ubuntu, only one swap and one ext4 as root.

Problem:
when I turn on the computer and it enters grub menu (i have grub2) these are the options:

- Ubuntu;
- Advanced options for ubuntu;
- Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4);
- System setup

and ubuntu starts up normally, but when I choose windows I get:

```
cannot find command 'drivemap';
invalid efi file path
```

However, when I alter the startup order in BIOS, options are: 1) Ubuntu, 2) Hard disk, 3) Windows 8 setup, so my hard drive, or Windows 8 setup be loaded first, Windows 8 starts up normally (without showing the grub menu)

I have found simmilar problems, and followed this instruction https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Multiboot_in_BIOS

I found here [Grub errors during UEFI dual boot for Windows 8 (can't find command 'drivemap')](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221311/grub-errors-dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu-12-10) though I didn't directly edit the `grub.cfg` file, I edited `40_custom` file in `/etc/grub.d`. I had some errors in writting though (they showed as I ran `grub-mkconfig -o grub.cfg`) so I didn't go through with it...

I shall appretiate any help. Mostly it concerns me that I cannot yet really pinpoint the problem.

Comment: check out this link [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system][^2]

  [^2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system

Comment: for this solution I should delete the ubuntu and reinstall it the right way, as I get it. right? well, the problem there is, my windows 8 was preinstalled so I don't have a cd, and I understood that I need it to be able to boot win8 after I delete ubuntu- or am I wrong? and also, is there another way, like simply to reinstall ubuntu, on the partition where it now is (is that doable?)?

Comment: yeah reinstall Ubuntu on the partition where it is now. Yes it is doable...when you are installing Ubuntu click on the option "something else" and then format the drive where you had installed Ubuntu and reinstall it on the same partition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purge and reinstall GRUB this way:

1. run `Boot-Repair` --> `Advanced options`
2. go to the "`GRUB options`" tab, tick "`Purge GRUB then reinstall it`"
3. click `Apply`

Indicate the new URL that will appear if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution given in [After installing Ubuntu I can't boot Windows 8 anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229858/after-installing-ubuntu-i-cant-boot-windows-8-anymore) ? 
It says to disable SecureBoot and FastBoot in your BIOS and then run Boot-Repair.

Comment: I deactivated SecureBoot before allready, forgot to mention it. Don't know what FastBoot option is, didn't find it.
I ran BootRepair from LiveCD ubuntu and it said there was an error of some kind (ubspecified), but it did do work - here is the pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1465556/

still the same problem occurs

Comment: **I forgot: the pastebin said: 'Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file!' but there is no such entry in boot options, just 'ubuntu'.

Answer (score 0):

yeah reinstall Ubuntu on the partition where it is now. Yes it is doable...when you are installing Ubuntu click on the option "something else" and then format the drive where you had installed Ubuntu and reinstall it on the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to supplement or replace GRUB. Be aware, though, that the "boot repair" utility others have been recommending renames the Windows boot loader file in a standards-violating way, which means that rEFInd won't be able to locate the Windows boot loader. If you haven't run the boot repair tool, this shouldn't be an issue; but if you have, you'll have to rename what is, in Linux, `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.bkp` to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, overwriting the file that currently uses the second name (it's a duplicate of GRUB). If the former file doesn't exist, this isn't an issue.