# After install ubuntu 12.10 cannot boot to windows 8 ( pre-installed)

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, windows-8, uefi

recently I have bought a lenovo z580 with pre installed windows 8 and I have installed ubuntu 12.10 ( secure boot was enabled when I was installing ubuntu after the installation I disabled it) I can boot to ubuntu with out a problem but I cannot boot to windows 8 from any where ( grub menu  or directly from the driver) .

the message from grub2 when I am trying to boot to windows 8 or windows 8 recovery is the same :

```
cannot find command 'drivemap';
invalid efi file path
```

if I try to boot directly to the hard disk then a blue screen popup with the message :

The boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors

```
File \EFI\Microsoft\BCD
error code 0xc000014c
```

You will need to use the recovery disk tools on your installation media.

I did not make a recovery disk :( so I cannot fix it by this way .

I try to boot to a windows 8 installation disk from msdna to call the recovery console but there I gives me the following message other error

The boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors

```
error code  0xc000000d
```

I have try to use boot-repair but it does not solve my problem.

here is the boot info before running the boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5576237/

here is the boot info after running the boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5576272/

Also I have try solve this by this way here [Dual boot Windows with Ubuntu 12.10 UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232602/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu-12-10-uefi) but with no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't attempt to use the `Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda5)` entry in GRUB to boot Windows; that's for a BIOS-mode installation of Windows, which you almost certainly don't have. The fact that this entry appears at all may be a bug in the GRUB configuration scripts. Instead, use the `>>Windows 8<<` entry. In theory, it should work -- although GRUB is finicky, so it might not, and your attempt to fix things from the Windows repair disk *might* have made matters worse.

If you can't seem to get GRUB working, you could try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Installing the Debian package from Ubuntu is the easiest way to do this. If this is successful, you'll see a rEFInd screen with an option to boot Windows and probably several options to boot Linux. If the Windows option and at least one Linux option work, you can trim the Linux options later by editing `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf`. Pay particular attention to the `dont_scan_files` option, which you can use to eliminate whatever options don't work or that you don't want to use. (You'll need to write down their filenames as displayed by rEFInd.)

Comment: thanks for your answer i will try it in a month ! ( seriously  )

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, this worked for me

insert Ubuntu cd and select try Ubuntu, connect to Internet open terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ),

login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

find out your linux disk :

```
fdisk -l
```

mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

Recover:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```